# Remove filter(jquery) on child table

Tags: jquery

I have a grid with child table(retractable). I have a field that helps with filtering the data since it is huge. The problem is that it is filtering the child table as well.
I am dynamically creating the parent and child table; how do I disable the filter on the child table? I have been able to remove the filter from the image that is used to retract the child table, but once filtered the child table is empty(because of the filter).

My jQuery code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#TextBox1").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#gridList  tr:not(td:eq(1)) ").filter(function() {
     
        $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
        
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: show html as well .

Comment: <table id="gridList" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table table-striped table-dark" style="margin-left:9px"><tr></tr><tr><td class="header"><img src="image/plus.png" /><DIV class="child" style="display: none"><table id="medicines" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class=" table table-striped table-dark"><tr style="background-color:#e87d7f;"><td>Category</td><td>Service Name</td><td>Ordered Qty</td><td>Qty Unit</td></tr>
<tr><td>Capsule/Tablets</td><td>WYSOLONE 20MG TAB</td><td>1</td><td>Tablet</td></tr></table></div></tr></table>

Answer (score 0):

Your selector `#gridList  tr:not(td:eq(1))` will find *all* `tr:...` that are in any way inside the `#gridList` element.

Try making it more specific like `gridList > tbody > tr:not(td:eq(1))` as this will only affect the first level `tr`s.

Without knowing your exact html I can only *guess* that the id `#gridList` was assigned to the `table` element. So, maybe the selector has to look slightly different for your specific html markup.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#TextBox1").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#gridList table tr:gt(0)").filter(function() {
        $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

```css
td {border: 1px solid gray; padding:4px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="TextBox1" placeholder="filter criterion ...">
<table id="gridList" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table table-striped table-dark" style="margin-left:9px">
  <tr></tr>
  <tr><td class="header"><img src="image/plus.png" /> Some Title<DIV class="child" style="display: nnone">
    <table id="medicines" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class=" table table-striped table-dark">
      <tr style="background-color:#e87d7f;"><td>Category</td><td>Service Name</td><td>Ordered Qty</td><td>Qty Unit</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Capsule/Tablets</td><td>WYSOLONE 20MG TAB</td><td>1</td><td>Tablet</td>
 <tr><td>Capsule/Tablets</td><td>ASPIRIN 300MG TAB</td><td>1</td><td>Tablet</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Suppositories</td><td>Paracetamol 400MG TAB</td><td>1</td><td>piece</td>   </table>
  </div></td></tr>
</table>
```

Now, with your html input (which was a little too short for a meaningful demonstration and also buggy in parts) I made a snippet, in which you can play around further. The above will probably do what you want.